# Generate random time for subactions inside of repeatActionforever under sequence for SWIFT

Tags: swift, random, sprite-kit, skaction

Hi I'm trying to generate random time intervals everytime the action is repeated but it only generates the time interval randomly only when the vied did load.

Here is my code :

```
 let moveBucketLeft = SKAction.moveByX(400, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(grabRandomTime()))
    let moveBucketRight = SKAction.moveByX(-400, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(grabRandomTime()))
    moveBucketLeftAndRight = SKAction.sequence([moveBucketLeft,moveBucketRight])
    let repeatMovement = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveBucketLeftAndRight)
    bucket.runAction(repeatMovement)
```

The method grabRandomTime just generates a random duration between 1 and 5 .

I need all the help I can help. Thank you!

Here's my generate random value method:

```
func grabRandomTime() ->UInt32{
    var time = arc4random_uniform(6) + 1
    return time
}
```

And the action runs one time in viewdidload. I think that maybe why it only take a random value one time. I'm not sure how to run the method everytime. I can't process that in my head :/

Comment: more context (code) needed. Be sure to run this code every time you want to run the action, and that the random method truly returns a random value (post the implementation of grabRandomTime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(sec, **withRange**: dur)` instead of `duration: NSTimeInterval(grabRandomTime()` in your code. SKAction.waitForDuration with withRange parameter will compute random time interval with average=sec and possible range = dur